# Merge E-Signature with DOC to PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, merge

I have E-Signature saved on png file with transparent BG and I want to merge it with a word document on a specific location on the document and saved it to one PDF by using C#
How can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

office interop.

It's quite involved so start by googling that to get started (opening the file, moving around, inserting picture, saving file.)

Comment: If you know a better way of doing it (which there isn't) post the answer, not just vote down the correct answer.